# Fetching rows if two columns have identical string or column is empty from postgres table in python

Tags: python, sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

I have following table in Postgres11.0

```
col1  col2       col3          col4
1     drug       Galactose     Galactose
2     biological Galactose_1   Galactose
3     drug       Galactose     Galactose
```

I am working on a python script which can compare two column values per row (col3 and col4), if they are equal and also fetching rows when col4 is empty. I am able to connect to the remote host and the database table and can fetch the rows as well. But the comparison operator giving syntax error. I am new to python so I am not able to find the error in my code.

```
q = "select * from %s.table;" % (staging_schema)
cur.execute(q)
print("Selecting rows from test table using cursor.fetchall")
row = cur.fetchall()
countdown = len(row)

for drug in row:
    if (drug[2] == drug[3]) or (drug[3] == '')
        print(countdown, drug[0], drug[1], drug[2], drug[3])
        countdown -= 1
    else
        print('different string')
```

PS: I also tried drug[3].isnull().

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler and more efficient to let the database do the work, rather than fetching the whole table and then iterate and filter in the application code.

You seem to want:

```
select *
from mytable
where col3 = col4 or col4 is null
```

This assumes that you mean `null` when you say *empty*. If you mean *empty string*, then:

```
where col3 = col4 or col4 = ''
```

Or just handle both:

```
where col3 = col4 or col4 is null or col4 = ''
```